Applying Memgraph Lab Graph Style editor styles to an Orb instance
I'm visualizing a network graph using Memgraph Lab. I have customized the styles for nodes and edges using the Graph Style editor. I want to create a dynamic web-based visualization using Orb. I need the Orb instance to have the same styles as those defined in the Memgraph Lab Graph Style editor.
I have styled the nodes based on their types with specific colors and sizes, and edges based on their relationships. When I update these styles in Memgraph Lab, I would like the changes to be reflected automatically in the Orb instance. Can this be done?

When using Orb, you don't need GSS. Lab uses GSS because it would be insecure and complicated to expose the Javascript/Typescript engine for a user to define custom styling - that is the reason behind the GSS engine. So GSS code is actually complied to the list of style parameters for each node, and this is not exposed currently in the Lab.
But with Orb you should be able to replicate the same behavior quickly because you can do the style rules in plain JS/TS. You can see how it is done here:
https://memgraph.com/blog/visualize-graphs-in-the-browser-with-just-a-few-lines-of-the-new-orb-code
